# Default argument in R function (formal argument matched by multiple actual arguments)

Tags: r, function, argument-passing

Simple question, I hope. I want to write a plotting function that has a default value for the y-axis label if the user doesn't specify. I'd also like to allow the `...` argument for other plotting parameters, and allow the user to set `ylab` manually. But I can't figure out how to do this.

```
# simple scatterplot function with a default ylab
scatter <- function(x,y, ...) {
    plot(x, y, ylab="Default y-axis label", ...)
}

# generate data
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x+rnorm(100)

# use the default
scatter(x,y)

# here I want to use my own label, but I get an error!
scatter(x, y, ylab="New y-axis label")
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in plot.default(x, y, ylab = "Default y-axis label", ...) : 
  formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I understand the problem, but I don't know the best way to fix it. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I realize I can do something like

```
scatter <- function(x,y,ylab = "Default y-axis label", ...) {
    plot(x, y, ylab= ylab, ...)
}
```

...but if I'm writing a package to submit to CRAN, and I have lots of default options I'd like to fiddle with, I don't want to have to document all these standard plotting arguments because they're used in my function definition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
scatter <- function(x,y,ylab = "Default y-axis label", ...) {
    plot(x, y, ylab= ylab, ...)
}
```

Expanding slightly on Arun's answer, this is a sketch of one route to take if you have many arguments:

```
def_args <- list(ylab = "Default Label",xlab = "Default Label")

scatter <- function(x,y, ...) {
    cl <- as.list(match.call())[-1L]
    do.call("plot",c(cl,def_args[!names(def_args) %in% names(cl)]))
}
```

Some thought would be needed to decide how you want to handle partial matching of arguments (if at all). e.g. perhaps something like this:

```
scatter <- function(x,y, ...) {
    cl <- as.list(match.call())[-1L]
    names(cl) <- match.arg(names(cl),
                           names(formals(plot.default)),several.ok = TRUE)
    do.call("plot",c(cl,def_args[!names(def_args) %in% names(cl)]))
}
```

would handle partial matching of arguments.

Comment: That works, but if I'm writing a package, it's yet another argument I have to document unnecessarily. I've got lots of these default plotting parameters I want to fiddle with but don't want to document again.

Comment: @StephenTurner It would take me a few minutes to work up an example, but one option would be to not provide an explicit default at all, but rather to pack everything in `...` and then inspect `...` inside `scatter` and then depending on what the user passed, construct an appropriate call to `plot`.

Comment: @StephenTurner i.e. _exactly_ what Arun just provided.

Comment: Thanks - will take a look at both of these solutions. You're right, the trick will be handling multiple permutations of specified and "default" options.

Comment: Thanks. Using `do.call` with the argument list provided here solved the problem perfectly. Seems like there'd be a less ick way of doing this, but this works fine.

Answer (score 5):

One way using `match.call` to check if `ylab` has been specified as an argument:

```
scatter <- function(x,y, ...) {
    mcall = as.list(match.call())[-1L]
    if (!"ylab" %in% names(mcall))
        plot(x, y, ylab="Default y-axis label", ...)
    else plot(x, y, ...)
}
```

As mentioned under comment `list(...)` is a nicer way to get just the dots argument expanded than having to get all the formal arguments with `match.call`.

You might also try using `pmatch` instead of `%in%` for partial matching of arguments.

Comment: Isn't `...` more easily captured as `args <- list(...)` inside the fxn?

Comment: Exactly. The trick in the OP's situation is probably going to be scaling this to work with a large number of arguments. I was thinking something along the lines of having a set of default arguments in a list ready to go, and then taking a "union" with `...` and then tossing it to `do.call` or something.

Answer (score 3):

I use a function to build an argument list.  In my case, I do not care about partially matching argument names, which is good because this won't support it.

```
# Create a list of input arguments.
# Allow arguments to be specified multiple times, first definition wins.
# The resulting list is intended to be passed to do.call().

make.args <- function(..., PRE.ARGS=list(), POST.ARGS=list()) {
  a <- list()
  l <- c(PRE.ARGS, list(...), POST.ARGS)
  for (name in unique(names(l))) {
    a[[name]] <- l[[name]] # First occurrence will be found.
  }
  return(a)
}
```

An example of its use:

```
plot.rate <- function(col, cond=NULL, ...) {
    col <- paste(col, collapse=' + ')
    f <- paste(col, '~ Rate')
    if (!is.null(cond)) {
        cond <- paste(cond, collapse=' + ')
        f <- paste(f, cond, sep='|')
    }

    arg.list <- make.args(...
                    , x = as.formula(f)
                    , main=col
                    , grid=TRUE
                    , scales=list(x=list(alternating=1)    # bottom(/left)
                                , y=list(alternating=3)) # both
                                , xlab='x RTM'
    )

    do.call(xyplot, arg.list)
}
```